# Возникает ошибка ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded

Tags: postgresql

```
    create or replace function get_beta_company_name(order_record orders)
    returns text as $$
begin
    return case
        when order_record.source_id = '141' then case
        when exists (
            select beta_company_name
            from v_delivery_orders
            where source_id = '141'
            and status_confirmed_at >= now() - interval '1 day'
            group by beta_company_name
            having avg(
                case when beta_company_name = '832' then 1 else 0 end
            ) > 0.7) then '831' else '832'
        end
    else case
        when order_record.is_courier = 1 then '800'
        else
            case
                when order_record.prime_cost <= 280 then '837'
                when 280 < order_record.prime_cost and order_record.prime_cost < 450 then '877'
                when 450 < order_record.prime_cost and order_record.prime_cost < 550 then '849'
                when 550 < order_record.prime_cost and order_record.prime_cost < 700 then '800'
                when 700 < order_record.prime_cost and order_record.prime_cost < 900 then '876'
                when 900 <= order_record.prime_cost then '848'
                else '800'
            end
        end
    end;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, происходит рекурсивный вызов данной функции